# How to Get JSON Results from Google Places JS Library using textsearch()?

Tags: javascript, json, google-places-api, google-places

**Question:** How can I get the ~same JSON response that I get when I call Google Places server-side API /textsearch/ in my browser, but using Google Places JS Library instead?

**Here is the server-side Google Places API /textsearch/**
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+pyrmont&key=AIzaSyAXPJDWXhzlAY0N8mMUcgFJ6yNSEd0vMg8

**Here is the sample code:**
I've tried to console.log() the JSON, but I can't get any JSON to log to the console.

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    query: 'restaurant'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];

      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
   console.log(place.id)
  }
}
```

Here's the documentation in case it's helpful: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Thats because you are logging only the ID, move your log after `var place...` and remove the `.id`. I tested this code and seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks, @yomisimie! 

I just made those changed, but am not getting the JSON logging to the console. Could it be the GP Library link I'm hitting... Are you using this one?


    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key=API_KEY&libraries=places" async defer></script>

Comment: Yes, I am using the places library. But I don't have the async and defer properties, I am using it in wordpress.

Comment: Ah! I see I got it. The async defer was the problem. I needed that to load before the JS ran. Thank you so much, @yomisimie! You guided me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad it worked man. The async i think was the problem, that waits a while before returning the results so you can't return it at document ready.